# Jade Render Header with 'active' Class

Tags: node.js, templates, pug

I'm struggling with what might be a simple Jade question.

I want to render a header that has the active page link rendered with the class 'active' applied, however I can't get the syntax correct. I've tried some variations of what I have below but with no luck.

```
ul.header
  li
    a(href='/' class=!{activePage} === 'home' ? 'active' : '') HOME
  li
    a(href='/one' class=!{activePage} === 'home' ? 'active' : '') ONE
  li
    a(href='/two' class=!{activePage} === 'home' ? 'active' : '') TWO
```

When I call render I pass an object like so.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    activePage: 'home'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ul.header
  li
    a(href='/', class=(activePage === 'home' ? 'active' : '')) HOME
  li
    a(href='/one', class=(activePage === 'one' ? 'active' : '')) ONE
  li
    a(href='/two', class=(activePage === 'two' ? 'active' : '')) TWO
```

Comment: I had tried that previously too, turns out I left out the comma between the href and class attributes!

Thanks Peter :)

Comment: Yes, that comma is probably the most annoying thing of jade syntax.